# PostgreSQL: case when using alias column

Tags: postgresql

I would like to do something like this:

```
select 
case when (select count(*) as score from users t1 )   >5   THEN score   else 0 end
```

When i try it i get error:

```
column score doesn't exists.
```

Can i do this in some other way? I need it to set a LIMIT value. I would like to do it of course in this way:

```
select 
case when (select count(*) as score from users t1 )   >5   THEN (select count(*) as score from users)    else 0 end
```

but than I need execute two times this same query. 
Have someone some ideas?

Comment: What about common table expression? It could help you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `WITH` clause:

```
with a as (select count(*) score from t)
select case when score > 5 then score else 0 end from a;
```

Or subquery (inline-view):

```
select case when score > 5 then score else 0 end 
from (select count(*) score from t) t;
```

Comment: Documentation link: [WITH Queries (Common Table Expressions)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html)